# Regarding Authorize attribute usage in ASP.Net MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

when we decorate any action with Authorize attribute then how MVC redirect to login form because my login controller name could be different and also view name also could be different. login view also could be stored in different folder instead of shared folder.

so tell me how MVC engine understand that it need to load login form when face Authorize attribute ?

how MVC engine would know where login form template is stored because it location could be different instead of shared folder?

how MVC engine would know what is login controller name if my login controller name is different ?

please discuss 3 points i asked here in details. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AuthorizeAttribute` is a filter, which means that it can execute before the associated controller action. The `AuthorizeAttribute` performs its main work in the `OnAuthorization` method. If the user fails authentication, an `HttpUnauthorizedResult` action result is returned which produced an HTTP 401 status code. In previous versions of ASP.NET MVC the user redirected to the application login page defined in the application's web.config:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Account/LogOn" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
```

In ASP.NET MVC 5, the redirection process is handled by `OWIN` middleware components. It redirects unauthenticated requests to a `LoginPath` value, which
defaults to "`/Account/Login`":

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
         AuthenticationType =
         DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
         LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
});
```

Comment: thanks for answer. so in ASP.NET MVC 5 there is no web.config file? if yes then why login action path should be hard coded?

Comment: In ASP.NET MVC 5 we have web.config. One more thing: you can set login path this way: `LoginPath = new PathString(url.Action("login", "account"))`